# Divergence of sequences and associated rate

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

I'm given with two sequences of positive reals $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ living in a compact set $\Omega$ so that $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ while $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} b_n$ may not even exist, and if it does, it is different from zero. Armed with these, I would like to show that:
$$
\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n b_k \le \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k
$$
does not hold true. Any suggestion on the argument I should make, or some counterexample? I'm tempted to say that the LHS diverges "faster" than the RHS, but this is of course not formal (and possibly not even true).

Comment: @ajotatxe just edited accordingly.

Comment: LHS diverges to infinity and RHS can converge or diverge to infinity, so the inequality (admitting that a real number is $<\infty$, which is a usual convention), is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LHS diverges to infinity and RHS can converge or diverge to infinity. Remeber that $k_n\to 0$ is a necessary condition (but not sufficient) for that $\sum k_n$ converges.

If $\sum a_n$ converges the inequaility is false. But if $\sum a_n=\infty$ I'd say that is is true. For example
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1n=\infty$$

Comment: Does it change anything if I have those sequences living in a compact set?

Comment: @GuidoLaremi no, in the counterexample, the $\{a_n\}$ sequence is contained in the set $[0,1]$, while the other sequence could be a constant sequence (i.e., as compact of a set as you can get). Take $a_n=1/n^2$ for a convergent series whose terms are still in $[0,1]$.